# Free all memory allocated by LLVM on exit

Tags: c, memory-leaks, llvm, valgrind

I am using LLVM-C to program a little toy language. 
I am using also valgrind to check for memory leaks.

Here is my basic baby program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>

int main()
{
    size_t length;
    LLVMModuleRef module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("llvm.hello");
    printf("Module name: %s\n", LLVMGetModuleIdentifier(module, &length));
    LLVMDisposeModule(module);
    LLVMShutDown();
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile and run the program normally, as expected. However when I run the program through valgrind, it tells me I have some "still reachable" allocated memory like this.

```sh
valgrind  --leak-check=full  out/hello_llvm
```

```
==5807== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5807==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5807==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5807==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5807==    still reachable: 56 bytes in 2 blocks
==5807==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

While searching over here on this site for an answer, I found many coders are saying that "still reachable" memory leaks are not such a big deal. I don't want to argue about that. What I want is to get rid of ALL allocated memory before terminating my program.

Is there any way I can reduce that allocated memory down to zero before termination?

Comment: If there is still reachable allocated memory after your `main` has lost any way to reach it, it must be pointed to from static objects. In other words, LLVM has some objects with static storage duration that are (directly or indirectly) pointing to allocated memory. Will valgrind show you more? You might have to dig into the LLVM sources to see what it is doing. It could make some sense to allocate some memory for long-term use across different calls, but it can be considered a design flaw.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I look at the detailed report given by valgrind, it seems that some allocations have been made for threading purpose but not freed... 

==7288==    by 0xA134826: __pthread_once_slow (pthread_once.c:116)
==7288==    by 0x580D675: llvm::ManagedStaticBase::RegisterManagedStatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also makes me very nervous when valgrind does not give 0, in those cases I create a suppression file, if you want to give it a try:

Create and compile a minimal test:

```
> cat demo.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    malloc(10); // leak
}
```

Create a supression file:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --gen-suppressions=all --log-file=minimal.supp ./demo
```

Edit the generated `minimal.supp` file, you will see something like

```
==3102== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3102== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3102== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3102== Command: ./demo
==3102== Parent PID: 2633
==3102== 
==3102== 
==3102== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3102==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3102==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==3102== 
==3102== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3102==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3102==    by 0x10915A: main (in /home/david/demo)
==3102== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc
   fun:main
}
==3102== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3102==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3102==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3102==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3102==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3102==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3102== 
==3102== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3102== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Remove all the lines starting with `==` and save something like:

```
{
   <my stupid external LLVM leak>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc
   fun:main
}
```

Now run valgrind with the supression file:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --error-limit=no --suppressions=minimal.supp ./demo
```

The result is:

```
==3348== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3348== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3348== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3348== Command: ./demo
==3348== 
==3348== 
==3348== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3348==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3348==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==3348== 
==3348== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3348==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3348==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3348==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3348==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3348==         suppressed: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==3348== 
==3348== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3348== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

As you can see, the leak is moved from "definitely lost" to "suppressed"

Comment: I like you answer as it solves part of my actual problem. I'll be able to suppress the errors I don't have control over and concentrate on my owns afterward. It doesn't give me a way to reduce to zero everything though, I mean deallocate the leaked residual memory in LLVM. But it could be that this is not possible or cleanly doable. Anyway, I'll wait a bit to see if someone can come up with that answer before accepting yours. Meanwhile, I'll apply your well detailed solution readily in my project. Thank ;-)

Comment: Thanks Frederic, yes, not exactly 0 but at least you have the control of your own leaks.

Comment: I just applied your solution and it works flawlessly. Thanks again.